# How do I streamline a TypeError for estimate_gas() in a sandbox terminal?

Tags: web3.py, python, command-line

I'm playing around in a command terminal using this [tutorial](https://snakecharmers.ethereum.org/a-developers-guide-to-ethereum-pt-1/) and I'm trying to send a transaction between two hashes and keep getting a "TypeError: estimate_gas() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" yet when I call each account their set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - what I was doing before was

tx_hash = w3.eth.send_transaction({
'from': w3.eth.accounts[0],
'to': w3.eth.accounts[1],
'value': w3.toWei(3, 'ether')
})

Yet it works when you add an arbitrary gas value, which make total sense.

tx_hash = w3.eth.send_transaction({
'from': w3.eth.accounts[0],
'to': w3.eth.accounts[1],
'gas' : 123456,
'value': w3.toWei(3, 'ether')
})